# Insert selective columns into collection using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, triggers, database-trigger, mongodb-atlas

Wrote a trigger function that inserts  full documents to my collection `new_list` when ever there is an insert into `listingsAndReviews` collection.

```
exports = function(changeEvent) {

    const fullDocument = changeEvent.fullDocument;

    const collection = context.services.get('Cluster0').db("sample_airbnb").collection("new_list");


    return collection.insertMany([fullDocument])
  .then(result => {
    console.log(`Successfully inserted ${result.insertedIds.length} items!`);
    return result;
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to insert documents: ${err}`));

};
```

Is there a way to select only particular required columns while inserting data into new_list collection.
In this case i need to insert only name and cart_id and ignore others.

My sample collection column names :

```
name     - string
cart_id   - objectid
number - string
address - string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract your required properties from `fullDocument` and just insert this new object:

```
return collection.insertMany([{name: fullDocument.name, cart_id: fullDocument.cart_id }])
```

Afaik there's no other way to "filter" properties on the `insert`-methods.
Also note that you can use `insertOne` here instead of `insertMany` as you're only inserting one document.

Comment: This means that `fullDocument` was already undefined, i.e. the `changeEvent` did not have `fullDocument` set.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - `changeEvent.fullDocument` is undefined, and thus `fullDocument` as well!